# Eclipse Neon and Git clone does not work

Tags: git, macos-sierra, eclipse-neon, github-enterprise

We are using Github Enterprise, and each user created its own personal access token, which is used in git clone.

However in Eclipse Neon (macOS) I tried to add manually cloned repository, and it not adds into Eclipse Git perspective.

So I tried to clone repo again using Eclipse Neon & its EGit,
when i'm cloning git manually i use this:

```
https://<USERNAME>:<TOKEN>@github.ibm.com/<ORGANIZATION>/<REPOSITORY>
```

When I use same URL in eclipse clone Git wizard:
[image]
, in after next button clicked i have this error:
[image]

Any ideas what could be wrong ?

## UPDATE:

I also tried access using SSH keys, which also work fine in console, but Eclipse has still issue after in enter URL:
[image]

Same window as picture 2)

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the token from the URI field in Eclipse Git.  You are passing in authentication parameters so you shouldn't need to also pass the token in the URI.  Should look something like this:

```
https://github.com/username/repo.git
```

Comment: actually I did but i have same issue see updated question

Comment: Is Eclipse listed under the 'Authorized Application' in GitHub?

Comment: [link](https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-ssh-keys-and-application-access-tokens-safe/#reviewing-your-authorized-applications-oauth)

Comment: finally solved it using SSH as protocol and different URL scheme.